# Titanium Alloy can't access third level nested object

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-alloy

I've ran into a problem with Titanium Alloy. I can't seem to access a 3d level nested object that is declared in the XML from the controller .

This is the layout in XML :

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="reportDetails"/>
    <Window class="container" title="Update Report Details" onClose="cleanup" >

        <View id="labels">          
            <TextArea id="jobTitle" class="title bold" editable="false"></TextArea>         
            <View class="jobTitleSecondPart" >
                <Label class='bold'>last date od service: </Label>
                <Label id="jobDate" class="stickLeft"></Label>
                <Label class='bold'>Job ID: #</Label>
                <Label id="jobId" class="stickLeft"></Label>
            </View>
        </View>
        <ActivityIndicator id="busy"></ActivityIndicator>
        <View height="Titanium.UI.FILL">
            <ScrollView  id="scrollIns" layout="vertical" dataCollection="reportDetails" dataFilter="filterFunction" height="Titanium.UI.FILL">
                <View id="instruction"> <!-- ***I am trying to access this object in the controlle***r -->
                    <Label class="title bold black">Agent Instructions :</Label>
                    <Label platform="android" id="jobInstruction" html="{agentInstructions}" class="black"   height="Titanium.UI.SIZE" />
                    <WebView platform="ios" id="jobInstruction" html="{agentInstructions}" class="black" touchEnabled="false" height="Titanium.UI.SIZE" />
                </View>
                <View id="comment">
                    <Label class="title bold black">Agent Comment :</Label>
                    <Label id="jobComment" class="black" text="{reportComment}"></Label>
                </View>
                <Require src="reportImageGallery" images="{images}"/>
            </ScrollView>
            <View id="buttons">
                <Button id="btnInsert" class="bold" onClick="showInsertReport">Insert Update Reports</Button>
            </View>
        </View>

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

This is the line of code from the controller :

$.instruction.visible = false;

And this is the error it gives me :

message = "undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.instruction.visible = false')";

Comment: one issue which i could think with your code is that you are using collection for scrollview; so basically the content within scrollview loops as many times as the rows in your reportDetails model. Hence  `id="instruction"` is also created multiple times (i.e rows.length); so when you try to fetch that id in controller it maybe getting confused because a xml file should have unique ids.

Comment: if you can explain your business logic; i will try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Turtle is correct that IDs inside a data-bound parent element (using `dataCollection`) cannot be used to reach them via `$.<id>` since there would be more then one instance.

Comment: Can I somehow use the value of “agentInstructions” parameter that i’m using as value in html="{agentInstructions}" to controll the visible parameter of the “instruction” element? …is it possible to use something similar like in adobe flex   .visible = “{agentInstructions !== ‘’ }” ?

Comment: You should add a `dataTransform` attribute with the name of a transform function that takes a model and returns any additional/changed properties. Then in the view use this property with visible="{isVisible}"

Comment: Although not quite flex - like, it works just fine, thanks a lot. By the way, one more question regarding the binding: how can I hide this “instruction” view when it’s not visible? To bind the visible parameter to a function, for example one that hides the view.

Comment: I solved this with another variable in the transform function but it would be nice to know if it’s possible to bind parameter/variable to function in tittanium.
var Instructionvisible = _model.attributes.agentInstructions !== "not set";
return parameter would be : instructionHeight: instructionVisible === true ? Titanium.UI.SIZE : 0

Comment: Not sure what your question is about that function?

Comment: My question is, I need to hide the view “instruction” when I receive some parameter from the transform function.Now I am doing that by setting it’s height to 0. How can I call hide() on this view when I need to?

Comment: You can do that by using the property coming form the transfrom function as a value for the "visible" attribute for that element you need to hide: <Label platform="android" visible="{visible}" id="jobInstruction" />